# After modifying machine.config VS crashes, also many components

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, machine.config

I am just trying to add

```
<system.transactions>
    <machinesettings maxtimeout="02:30:00">
    </machinesettings>
</system.transactions>
```

section to the end of my machine.config local file so I test out a transaction that lasts for too long.
The transaction is initialized from my local windows app communicating to SQL server.

So the end of machine.config file now looks like:

```
...
</providers>
        </roleManager>
    </system.web>
    <system.transactions>
        <machinesettings maxtimeout="02:30:00">
        </machinesettings>
    </system.transactions>
</configuration>
```

[This](http://textuploader.com/n68p) is my machine config file now.

I am modifying both
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config

I am following advice given at the [link](http://thecodesaysitall.blogspot.se/2012/04/long-running-systemtransactions.html)

But, when I do this and reopen the app, VS studio project loading fails with the message:
The .Net Trace handling fails. Please check your .Net machine and enterprise configuration.

Should I do something else after modifying machine.config ?
Is there some quick way to get out of this as this is the fourth thing in the row I am doing only to increase the timeout.

Thank you for the time!

Comment: Check whether system.transactions has been defined before on the file. Having a double section may confuse it.

Comment: There is just the section defiition before. Is that all fine?
I have copy/pasted the section here: http://textuploader.com/njsj

Comment: First thing that stands out, it should be `machineSettings`, note capital S, second, check the nesting, it's hard to see on my mobile, but it looks like it should be a subsection of `system.componentModel`

Comment: You are right jesse. In the meantime, I tried with capital letters on my own and figured out that is the issue.
It should not be child of system.componentModel , it should be subsection of configuration. It was all about capital letters, I am running tests now

Answer (score 2):

Resolved:

machine.config is case sensitive.
So the section should be:

```
<system.transactions>
    <machineSettings maxTimeout="02:30:00">
    </machineSettings>
</system.transactions>
```

my text was all in lower cases